# If condition not working in script over ssh

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, quoting, test

Below shell script on SSH mode is not working.

variable end_pos is getting value "Stop", but when it comes in IF loop , it doesn't check the condition and loop is getting failed.

Output of command :

```
 /mysql/mysql/bin/mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000001 |tail -10| grep -w -A1 154 | grep -w "Stop" |awk '{print \$10}'
```

is STOP

echo \$end_pos; print STOP

```
 #!/bin/bash
ssh -t -t username@hostname << ENDSSH
  cd /logs
echo "8. We are in SSH mode now" >./log_master.txt
end_pos=\$(/mysql/mysql/bin/mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000001 |tail -10| grep -w -A1 154 | grep -w "Stop" |awk '{print \$10}')
echo \$end_pos;

 if  [ "\$end_pos" == "*Stop*" ];
  then
     echo "Loop succeed" >>./log_master.txt
 break
  else
      echo "loop failed" >>./log_master.txt
 fi
exit;
exit;
ENDSSH
```

After ilkKachu comment i put quotes in "ENDSSH" ( this is the only change i made) and executed .It threw error.
Then i used second method of putting double brackets as shown below .

But when executed below  script , i was getting this : if  [[ "" = "*Stop*" ]];

```
  #!/bin/bash
 ssh -t -t username@hostname << ENDSSH
 cd /logs
 echo "8. We are in SSH mode now" >./log_master.txt
end_pos=\$(/mysql/mysql/bin/mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000001 |tail -10| grep -w -A1 154 | grep -w "Stop" |awk '{print \$10}')
 echo \$end_pos;

if  [[ "$end_pos" == "*Stop*" ]];
 then
 echo "Loop succeed" >>./log_master.txt
 break
 else
  echo "loop failed" >>./log_master.txt
fi
exit;
ENDSSH
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this in below way :

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t -t username@hostname << ENDSSH
 cd /logs
 echo "8. We are in SSH mode now" >./log_master.txt
end_pos=\$(/mysql/mysql/bin/mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000001 |tail -10| grep -w -A1 154 | grep -w "Stop" |awk '{print \$10}')
 echo \$end_pos;

if  [[ "$end_pos" =~ Stop ]];
 then
 echo "Loop succeed" >>./log_master.txt
 else
 echo "loop failed" >>./log_master.txt
fi   
exit;
ENDSSH
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh -t -t username@hostname << ENDSSH
...
echo \$end_pos;
```

If you don't need to expand any variables from the outer shell to the here-doc that goes to SSH, you can use `<< "ENDSSH"` with quotes around the delimiter, to have the here-doc taken as if a single-quoted string. Then you don't need to escape every `$` sign within it.

```
if [ "$end_pos" == "*Stop*" ]; then
```

If you want to compare the value against `*Stop*` as a *pattern*, and not as a *literal* string, you need to use `[[ .. ]]` or the more standard `case`:

```
if [[ $end_pos = *Stop* ]] ; then
    ...

# or
case "$end_pos" in 
    *Stop*) echo "stop found" ;;
    *) echo "stop not found" ;;
esac
```

Also, that `break` looks out of place, there is no loop. Bash will complain about that, but only if that part of the if-statement is executed. Two `exit`s in a row seem a bit redundant, too.

Comment: Thanks for reply . but both ways it is not working. I have shown in edit part what i did after reading your comment

Comment: @user21546, you don't have the quotes around the `ENDSSH` keyword, you only removed the escapes from the `$`s. Which means the variable gets expanded by the script calling `ssh`, and it doesn't have a value there, so you get empty. I meant you could write `ssh -t ... << "ENDSSH"` (or `<< 'ENDSSH'`), literally, _with the quotes_. But it doesn't matter, if you leave the terminator unquoted, then just escape the `$`s, as in your original code. That part is just a style issue.